# Is there a Russian analogue of British Council or Goethe-Institut?

Tags: обучение

As far as I know, for English, German, French there are state organizations promoting these languages abroad. Does Russia have anything similar?

Comment: [The Pushkin State Russian Language Institute](http://www1.pushkin.edu.ru/publ/english/pushkin_institute_info/53-1-0-188)

Comment: The link user844 left above did not work for me.  If you experienced the same, try this one: [**Pushkin State Russian Language Institute.**](http://www.pushkin.institute/en/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exists the so-called [МАПРЯЛ](http://www.mapryal.org/) — Международная Ассоциация Преподавателей Русского Языка и Литературы — this is the closest institution of such kind I can recall.

To be honest, the Russian government is not doing its best in promoting national culture as well as national language. Taking a look at the last 20 years, there is a stable decline of knowing Russian as a foreign language even in ex-USSR countries.

So there is no Russian equivalent that is as influential and global as the British Council or Goethe-Institut.

Comment: I agree with the evaluation of the effort. Thanks for the link any way.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should take a look at [Russian Language Abroad](http://www.russianedu.ru/magazine/archive.html) (`Русский язык за рубежом`) magazine. [Russkiy Mir Foundation](http://www.russkiymir.ru/russkiymir/ru/) (`Фонд "Русский мир"`) is a good source, too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's anything akin to British Council, French Institute or Goethe-Institut for the Russian language.

That said, Russian embassies across the world often organize events for Russian language learners, as do Russian school abroad.