# Russian speech contest

Tags: обучение

Is there any official speech contest for foreigners learning Russian, akin to the [Japanese Speech Awards](http://www.iware.ne.jp/jsa/) (JSA)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly a "language" question. Ok it's about the language, but not about the language, if you get what I mean. :P

Comment: Philip, could you please justify what do you mean? I believe most of us cannot understand Japanese :)

Comment: JSA is an international speech contest for Japanese language learners. Best foreign Japanese speakers are chosen from high schools and universities teaching Japanese through qualifying round in individual countries (UK, Russia, etc. - generally organized by local Japanese embassies or cultural centers), and then compete for the main award in Tokyo. There are several categories depending on your age and level of Japanese, some with set topics, and the qualification rounds are very competitive with top Japanese teachers preparing their best students for the event.

Comment: Looks like it is something like this http://www.rg.ru/2011/03/29/rusolymp.html or http://www.svetozar.ru/

Answer (score 2):

This question is somewhat related to the [question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/272/is-there-a-russian-analogue-of-british-council-or-goethe-institut/719#719) "Is there a Russian analogue of British Council or Goethe-Institut".

All boils down to the fact that there does not exists such strong institution which can provide such contest on appropriate level.

Yet, in the year 2011 such contest has been conducted. So called "[1-й](http://www.russkiymir.ru/russkiymir/ru/news/common/news24075.html) всемирный фестиваль русского языка" (under МАПРЯЛ guidance), as far as I know, included, among other things, speech contest as well.

I've never heard about the second one.

As for link, provided by Roman Yankovsky, it's a little bit different story, since (correct me someone who knows this staff better, I might be wrong) major part of contestant were foreign pupils that had studied in russian schools.

Comment: What about the Russkiy Mir Foundation? "In June 2007 President Putin signed a decree establishing the Russkiy Mir Foundation, for the purpose of “promoting the Russian language, as Russia's national heritage and a significant aspect of Russian and world culture, and supporting Russian language teaching programs abroad.” The Foundation is a joint project of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs and the Ministry of Education and Science and supported by both public and private funds"